# Graph API to access my posts "user_posts" without long business verification process

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am doing an exercise to download all my Facebook posts data (posts, likes, reactions, comments...), and I did not find another way but to use Graph API.
Process:
Create a developer account, create an app, App review (check Facebook link https://developers.facebook.com/docs/permissions/reference/user_posts), but I don't want to invest in all of that, I am not creating a business, I just want to download all the data related to my posts.

I have tried to get this data from the activity log, but it only shows the actions I did, not the likes done by others...

Can you help

[image]

Comment: You should not need app review, if you are only using the app yourself. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/development/build-and-test/app-roles

Comment: @CBroe How can I make that happen? How can I grant myself full permission?

Comment: You grant your app permissions, by asking for them when the user logs in. So either implement login, or use Graph API Explorer to generate yourself a token with the needed permissions from there.

Comment: @CBroe In the list of permissions (check the screenshot in the original post), I only see 2-3 basic permissions, I don't see the "user_posts" for instance

Comment: Start typing into the "Add a permission" field ...

Comment: nothing, just the options in the screenshot, and if I write "user_posts", I cannot save.

Comment: Then you probably chose an unsuitable app type during app creation, I suppose. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/development/create-an-app